# Why can't jQuery UI sortable elements be dragged from a handle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page that add fields to a fake form so that the user can look at it before generating the source.

I'm trying to give the user the ability to sort and order the fields inside the form. I use jQuery for my ajax and animations, so I decided to use jquery UI to do the sorting.

My fields are added dinamicly, so I delegate all my events, and I use the `sortable('refresh');` every time a new field is added.

My GUI has icons for fields options, so I added the `handle` option to the `sortable()` method, but it doesn't recognize it at all!

Here is a demo of the GUI with the problem (it's in arabic and still in alpha so no IE7-6 support, but it uses icons so it will be easy to use ^^): http://mahersalam.co.cc/projects/namodgMaker/

Just add any field from the red buttons, and try to drag from the drag button, it doesn't work. If I remove the `handle` it works perfectly!

You can see that I log the `handle` value to the console, but it always logs the sortable object... There is a global object `NamodgMaker` is you want to experiment with it.

Here is the part that adds the fields and attach the `sortable()` method:

```
addField: function( type ) {

    var $html = $(this.fields[type]); // 'this' here is NamodgMaker, and `fields` is from an ajax request

    if (type == 'select') {
        $html
            .find('select')
                .styleNamodgSelects({
                    optionsRight: -6,
                    optionsTop: 38
                });
    }

    $html.appendTo(this.formHolder);

    if ( this.formHolder.data('sortable') ) {

        this.formHolder.sortable('refresh');
        console.log( this.formHolder.sortable( "option", "handle" ) );
        return
    }

    this.formHolder
        .sortable({
            containment: 'parent',
            handle: '.drag-field-option'
        })
        .data('sortable', true)

    console.log( this.formHolder.sortable( "option", "handle" ) );
}
```

This is my first time with jQuery UI, So what am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I found out that the `$.data()` was causing `sortable` to return the wrong options. I modified the code to use `sortable()`'s own checking method:

```
addField: function( type ) {

    var $html = $(this.fields[type]);

    if (type == 'select') {
        $html
            .find('select')
                .styleNamodgSelects({
                    optionsRight: -6,
                    optionsTop: 38
                });
    }

    $html.appendTo(this.formHolder);

    if ( ! this.formHolder.sortable( "option", "disabled")  ) {

        this.formHolder.sortable('refresh');
        console.log( 'refreshed :' + this.formHolder.sortable( "option", "handle" ) );
        return
    }

    this.formHolder
        .sortable({
            containment: 'parent',
            handle: '.drag-field-option'
        })


    console.log( this.formHolder.sortable( "option", "handle" ) );
}
```

Now the console logs the right selector but still the sorting functionality is not working.

**Update 2**: I was able to solve the problem by changing the handle element from a `button` to a `a`.

Comment: So it is really a hard problem, I thought It was only a small problem given that this is my first time with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to change my handle from a `button` to `a`. Seems that jquery UI doesn't like semantic markup!

Comment: Looks like this is currently a known bug with jQuery UI sortable - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5926